# How to use extern cuda device variables

Tags: c, cuda, header-files

I need to write the code into several .cu files. But where should I define the **device** variables which are use for many .cu files.

An example

File common.h

```
__device__ int x;
```

File A.cu

```
__global__ void a()
```

File B.cu

```
__global__ void b()
```

a(),b() both use x. what should I do?

In C language, I should write something like
extern **device** int x;
Then I define **device** int x in another place. But in CUDA I can not do it. If I do, it tells me ‘..........’ previously declared here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT** : @talonmies was right (as usual).  So I've deleted my comment about CUDA 4.1

Furthermore the compiling commands I gave were not quite right.  So let me replace my answer with one that demonstrably works and has the proper instructions.

*You need CUDA 5.0 and a compute capability 2.0 or greater device for this to work.*

I'm sure there's probably a better way, but this seems to work for me:

com.h:

```
#ifndef DEVMAIN
extern __device__ int x;
#endif
```

a.cu:

```
#include "com.h"
__global__ void a(){

  x = -5;
}
```

b.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEVMAIN
#include "com.h"

extern __global__ void a();
__device__ int x;

__global__ void b(){

  x = 5;
}

int main() {
  int temp=7;
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(x,&temp, sizeof(int));
  a<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&temp,x,sizeof(int));
  printf("in host : %d\n",temp);
  b<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&temp,x,sizeof(int));
  printf("in host2 : %d\n",temp);
  return 0;
}
```

compiling:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -dc a.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -dc b.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o ab a.o b.o
```

output:

```
$ ./ab
in host : -5
in host2 : 5
$
```

Sorry for my previous errors.

Comment: Worth pointing out this is probably only legal in CUDA 5  which has a proper device code linker.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I tried your code, could you please try this code,it should be 1,-1 but it is 1,1.? `int main() {
 int temp;
 b<<<1,1>>>();
 cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&temp,x,sizeof(int),0,D_T_H);
 printf("in host : %d\n",temp);
  a<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&temp,x,sizeof(int),0,D_T_H);
  printf("in host2 : %d\n",temp);

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}`

Comment: @RobertCrovella and D_T_H is `#define D_T_H cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost`

Comment: @worldterminator I have made several mistakes in my previous answer so I have fixed those (I hope) and edited my answer with the changes.

Comment: Yeah, it works! BTW, could you tell me what does -dc mean? What's the differences from -c?

Comment: You'll find the answer [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#code-changes-for-separate-compilation).  With CUDA 5, we can now link device code separately.  In order to do this, the compiled device code has to be delivered to the linker in a relocatable format.  -dc instructs the compiler to generate relocatable device code which can be linked later.