# Duplicate symbol issue with C headers

Tags: c++, c, cuda, header-files, duplicate-symbol

This is my first time tackling a CUDA project that's slightly more complex than the simple write-single-source-file-and-compile routine. As expected, I'm facing some issues with C headers, namely duplicated symbols.

According to the linker, conflicts arise over the inclusion of the following header file in multiple `.cu` files:

**env_vars.h**

```
#ifndef ENV_VARS_H_
#define ENV_VARS_H_

/*** GLOBAL VARIABLES ***/
unsigned int h_n_osc;
__device__ unsigned int d_n_osc;

/*** CONSTANTS ***/
const double OMEGA_0 = 6.447421494058077e+09;

/* other constants defined in the middle */

#endif
```

**multigpu.cu**

```
#include "env_vars.h"
/* assigns h_n_osc */
```

**adm_matrix.cu**

```
#include "env_vars.h"
/* uses h_n_osc */
```

Building the project in Nsight Eclipse Edition results in the linker complaining about the `h_n_osc` variable being defined twice:

```
duplicate symbol _h_n_osc in:
    ./adm_matrix.o
    ./multigpu.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

Searching through the Internet, I've realized that moving the declaration of the `h_n_osc` variable to `multigpu.cu` and re-declaring it as an `extern` variable in `adm_matrix.cu` (and wherever I might need it later) solves the problem, *which in fact it does*.

Problem solved, but I'd like to take a deeper look into this:

1. Why doesn't the linker complain about the `d_n_osc` variable as well? And why are the constants (such as `OMEGA_0`) equally not a problem?
2. Does this mean that it is not possible to place global variables in header files?
3. What puzzles me most is that a number of sources over the Internet state that duplicated symbol errors should happen only when the header file contains a *definition* of the variable, while its simple *declaration* shouldn't constitute a problem. The reason I have a hard time believing this is that I'm facing the issue even though my header only contains a declaration! Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your patience, folks!

Comment: Believe it or not, `unsigned int h_n_osc;` is a definition.

Comment: define the variables in a single .c file,  then the header file needs 'extern' statements for those variables

Comment: Shocking revelations, @aschepler ! It turns out I've always misconceived the difference between declaration and definition of variables. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Header files should normally contain *only* declarative code. `h_n_osc` should be *declared* here, not *defined*.

```
extern unsigned int h_n_osc;
```

In at least one of your modules, or a new one of its own you will need a definition; for example:

**env_vars.cu**

```
#include "env_vars.h"
unsigned int h_n_osc;
```

Then link that.  Alternatively you could of course place the *definition* in one of the existing modules multigpu.cu or adm_matrix.cu.

I am not sure of the semantics of the The [CUDA `__device__`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-variable-qualifier) extension, while it may link, it is not necessarily correct; you may end up with each module referencing a *separate copy* of the device variable; it may be necessary to qualify that with `extern` as well.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597707/how-to-use-extern-cuda-device-variables) appears to deal with that issue.

Comment: Correct, `__device__` (and `__constant__`) variables [have file/translation unit scope](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-declarations).

Comment: @RobertCrovella :  Thanks; so they have the similar semantics to `static` and `const`?

Comment: It seems to be a [complicated topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709207/c-semantics-of-static-const-vs-const).  But I would say yes, similar.  In the absence of other specifics, CUDA should behave similarly to a C++ compiler. `__device__` and `__constant__` variables are not referencable in ordinary host C++ code, but that is a separate topic.

Comment: Thanks to you too, guys! As I commented above, most of my doubts clearly stemmed from my misunderstanding of the concepts of declaration and definition of a variable.
For the sake of completeness, [a little navigation](http://bit.ly/1rSDpH5) here on Stack Overflow also answered to question 2 in my original post: `const`ants have default internal linkage in C++ (whereas they default to external linkage in plain C), so my solution (i.e. defining them in the header) works fine just because CUDA C is actually CUDA C/C++; a pure C compiler would have rejected the constants, too.

Comment: @thequanticlad : If you declare const's `static const` the semantics are then the same in C and C++.  However if your code takes the address of the const, they will be different in each module, however in C++ at least if you don't take the address of a const, all references are replaced with literals.